# "Hooker", "whore", "prostitute", when to use which?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, offensive-language

"Hooker", "whore", and "prostitute" all mean *whore*; what are the differences between them?

Comment: You forgot "slut"... :D

Comment: Colloquially, "slut" does not imply that money or other payment changed hands, where as "hooker," "whore" and "prostitute" do.

Comment: Whoever is cheapest!

Comment: He missed out "harlot"

Comment: Other terms are "call girl" and "working girl".

Comment: but there is a distinction between a hooker and a call girl. A hooker openly hawks her wares ( sometimes as a "streetwalker"), putting herself physically in danger of arrest while offering and agreeing.  A callgirl arrarnges trysts by phone (or nowadays, by internet), either "incall" (her place) or "outcall" (his place). Both are, of couse, prostitutes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

They all can mean women who sleep with men for money. *Prostitute* is the most technical term. *Hooker* seems most commonly used in the United States, while in Britain this term is reserved for a position in rugby. *Whore* sounds much more violent to me. If one were seeking a woman to pay to sleep with him, he probably wouldn't say "I'm looking for a *whore* tonight," but use *hooker* or *prostitute*.

Calling someone a *whore* can be used to insult them, implying they sleep with many people (though for men the term would be *man-whore*). E.g., "She is such a whore." Going back to a previous example, "I'm looking for a *whore* tonight" implies more to me that he is looking for someone who is easy to sleep with, not for a prostitute.

Not to say you can't use the others in an insult. From "Baby Got Back," by Sir Mix-A-Lot, we also have the opening dialogue:

> They only talk to her, because,
>   she looks like a total *prostitute*, 'kay?

But in this case the lady quoted is just saying that she looks like a prostitute, not that she *is* one, necessarily. If she said "She is such a *prostitute*," that would mean that is her profession, not that she sleeps with a lot of men for free.

Comment: I wouldn't think "hooker" is most commonly used on the right-hand side of the pond, as in British English it means the man in the middle of the front row on the rugby pitch.

Comment: Definitely agree with Brian.  Whilst the term is understood in British English, the primary meaning is a rugby position.  Usually occupied by the shortest stocky person on the team, a similar role to the centre in a faceoff in Ice Hockey. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_union_positions#2._Hooker

Comment: thanks for the commments! I've updated the answer. learn new things every day. what is most commonly used in Britain?

Comment: without claiming any special expertise, I'd suggest the commonest is probably "tart".

Comment: I suppose it was bound to happen [sooner or later](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-leicestershire-57510121).

Answer (score 28):

Claudiu pretty much covered it, but there's one thing more to discuss. "Whore" has an unsavory meaning, to be sure, but it's lately been used in a milder sense, to describe someone who will do just about anything to get something he or she wants. In this case it is coupled with another noun. Examples:

> - **attention whore**: Someone who will do anything to get attention
> - **loot whore**: in MMORPG games, someone who will do anything to get gear
> - **rep whore**: on StackExchange sites, someone who will do anything to gain reputation

This is still a derogatory term, but it can also be used among friends in a somewhat affectionate sense. But the meaning can vary depending on how it is said: "Jill is *such* an attention whore" can mean you think she's obnoxious or funny, depending on how much you like Jill.

Answer (score 7):

If you're after the politically correct term, it's "Sex worker".

Answer (score 1):

The reason "hooker" is in common use in America (and not elsewhere), is because it is named after a U.S. Civil War general, Joseph Hooker (who let such women follow his troops around, contributing to lax discipline that led to defeat in battle).

Comment: General Hooker's name *reinforced* the existing word.  It actually derived from Hoek van Holland (the Hook of Holland), a Dutch seaport, famed as a venue for the pursuit of that vocation.

Comment: @malvolio: Fair enough. I'm just giving the American interpretation. So General Hooker was a "reinforcement" eh? In the war, he was best in that role (sometimes tipped the balance). He always lost as a "front line" man.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting discussion with excellent answers. There is **at least one more dimension: the "Latinization" of English.**

Online Etymological Dictionary (emphasis modified)

> [whore (n.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=whore&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> 1530s spelling alteration (see wh-) of Middle English hore, **from Old English** hore "prostitute, harlot," from Proto-Germanic *horaz (fem.
>   *horon-) "one who desires" (cognates: Old Norse hora "adulteress," Danish hore, Swedish hora, Dutch hoer, Old High German huora "whore;"
>   in Gothic only in the masc. hors "adulterer, fornicator," also as a
>   verb, horinon "commit adultery"), **[from PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language)** *ka- "to like, desire," a
>   base that has produced words in other languages for "lover" (**cognates: Latin** carus "dear;" Old Irish cara "friend;" Old Persian kama
>   "desire;" Sanskrit Kama, name of the Hindu god of love, kamah "love,
>   desire," the first element in Kama Sutra).

Compare with

> [prostitute (v.)](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prostitute&allowed_in_frame=0)
>
> 1520s, "to offer to indiscriminate sexual intercourse (usually in
>   exchange for money)," **from Latin** prostitutus, past participle of
>   prostituere "to expose to prostitution, expose publicly," from pro-
>   "before" (see pro-) + statuere "cause to stand, establish," **from PIE**
>   root *sta- "to stand."

The development of the two words are unusually dissimilar considering the similarities of their modern English meanings.

[English is technically a Germanic language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_languages), but modern English contains many more words from Latin and Romance languages than from Germanic or Anglo-Saxon sources. One pie chart on Wikipedia claims that [58% of the English lexicon is Latin or Romance and only 26% is Germanic.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_influence_in_English)

Many things have contributed to Latin's strong influence in modern English. [Some of the best analysis of Latin's influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_purism_in_English) comes from writers who are fiercely opposed to the Latinization.

When looking at the modern usage of "whore" and "prostitute", the general rule that most people *feel* that Latin words are more formal, proper, or acceptable in "polite society." The other answers support this idea: whore is much more insulting than prostitute.

The full etymological entries are packed with interesting facts about both words, so if you find this interesting, I recommend clicking the above links.

**Conclusion: both words exist in English because of the Latinization of English and people's need for a word that is not so crude that it is unacceptable in some situations.**

Answer (score 0):

**Prostitute**: The long technical term a person who has sex for money.
**Hooker**: A slang term for a prostitute.
**Whore**: A Derogative term for a prostitute or loose woman.